# Count unique values by group

Tags: r, dplyr

```
    DATA = data.frame("TRIMESTER" = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3),
                      "STUDENT" = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,5,9,10,11,3,7,10,6,12,15,17,16,21))
    
    WANT = data.frame("TRIMESTER" = c(1,2,3),
                      "NEW_ENROLL" = c(7,3,5),
                      "TOTAL_ENROLL" = c(7,10,15))
```

I Have 'DATA' and want to make 'WANT' which has three columns and for every 'TRIMESTER' you count the number of NEW 'STUDENT' and then for 'TOTAL_ENROLL' you just count the total number of unique 'STUDENT' every trimester.

My attempt only counts the number for each TRIMESTER.

```
library(dplyr)
DATA %>%
group_by(TRIMESTER) %>%
count()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a way.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))

DATA <- data.frame("TRIMESTER" = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3),
                  "STUDENT" = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,5,9,10,11,3,7,10,6,12,15,17,16,21))
DATA %>% 
  mutate(NEW_ENROLL = !duplicated(STUDENT)) %>%
  group_by(TRIMESTER) %>%
  summarise(NEW_ENROLL = sum(NEW_ENROLL)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(TOTAL_ENROLL = cumsum(NEW_ENROLL))
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   TRIMESTER NEW_ENROLL TOTAL_ENROLL
#>       <dbl>      <int>        <int>
#> 1         1          7            7
#> 2         2          3           10
#> 3         3          5           15
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 9):

- For variety we can use `Base R` `aggregate` with `transform`

```
transform(aggregate(. ~ TRIMESTER , DATA[!duplicated(DATA$STUDENT),] , length),
         TOTAL_ENROLL = cumsum(STUDENT))
```

- Output

```
  TRIMESTER STUDENT TOTAL_ENROLL
1         1       7            7
2         2       3           10
3         3       5           15
```

Answer (score 4):

We `replace` the `duplicated` elements in 'STUDENT' to `NA`, grouped by `TRIMESTER`, get the `sum` of nonNA elements and finally do the cumulative sum (`cumsum`)

```
library(dplyr)
DATA %>%
   mutate(STUDENT = replace(STUDENT, duplicated(STUDENT), NA)) %>% 
  group_by(TRIMESTER) %>% 
  summarise(NEW_ENROLL = sum(!is.na(STUDENT)), .groups= 'drop') %>%
  mutate(TOTAL_ENROLL = cumsum(NEW_ENROLL))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  TRIMESTER NEW_ENROLL TOTAL_ENROLL
      <dbl>      <int>        <int>
1         1          7            7
2         2          3           10
3         3          5           15
```

---

Or with `distinct`

```
distinct(DATA, STUDENT, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
 group_by(TRIMESTER) %>% 
 summarise(NEW_ENROLL = n(), .groups = 'drop') %>% 
 mutate(TOTAL_ENROLL = cumsum(NEW_ENROLL))
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  TRIMESTER NEW_ENROLL TOTAL_ENROLL
      <dbl>      <int>        <int>
1         1          7            7
2         2          3           10
3         3          5           15
```